# Is it possible to run time-based warmup phase using Jmh?

Tags: java, benchmarking, jmh

Is it possible to run time-based warmup phase using Jmh? I am using different parameters for benchmarker, and some of them consumes a lot of time, which is waste of time (no performance increase).

How can I tell to jmh that I want warmup for like 1 minute and then terminate? no matter how many iterations is executed?

Thanks

Comment: There is a timeout parameter `-to` but I don't know if that can help for your use case. How long is your benchmark?

Comment: it depends on used dataset. it can scale from miliseconds to minutes. and ofc. 10 iterations of 50 milisecond benchmak makes more sense than 10 iterations of one minute benchmark.

Comment: If you know that a specific benchmark takes one minute, you can annotate it to have a lower number of warmup iterations.

Comment: I thought about that. It's one possible solution, but I have many parameters and it's hard work to create separate test for each, that's why I asked.